# Not Entering an if Condition even if statements are valid

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

My error in my code that even though "A" , "B", "C" exist in the array the if condition inside the inner loop doesn't recognize them. Note that ABC is from a string that has been splitted using the String.split(""); method of java

```
public class Hexadecimal
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            String hex = "ABC";
            hToD(hex);
    }

    public static void hToD(String hexa)
    {
        String[] hexadecimal = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F"};
        String[] value = hexa.split("");

        int deci = 0;
        int bit =0;

        for(int i = 0; i<value.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<hexadecimal.length;j++)
            {
                if(value[i] == hexadecimal[j])
                {
                    deci = deci + compute(j,bit++);
                    System.out.println(deci);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static int compute(int digit,int bit)
    {
        int ans = 0;
        if(bit == 0)
        {
            ans = digit * (1);
        }else
        {
            ans = digit * (16 * bit);
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Comment: You know you are checking for *same object*, not *same string content*, don't you?

Comment: Oh my bad. I was actually comparing values. but I guess the == is for comparing if they have the same reference

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Never compare Strings with `==`. Always with `s1.equals(s2)`.

The former tests that both objects are the same (i.e. the variables reference the same String object). The latter tests that the sequences of chars of both Strings are the same.

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot. String is an Object. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Try using .equals() instead of == in that inner if statement.

```
if(value[i].equals(hexadecimal[j]))
```